# How would one iterate over embedded documents in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, embedded-documents

I'm in the midst of learning meteorJS, so kindly forgive my ignorance at the moment.

I have a tasks collection at the back end MongoDB which contains something like this:

```
{
    "name": Something",
    "Address": {
        "Building": A,
        "Street": B,
        "Locality": C
        }
}
```

My HTML page that contains the template looks like this:

```
{{#each tasks}}

        {{> task}}

  {{/each}}

<template name="task">

  <li>{{Name}}</li>
<li>{{Address}}</li>
</task>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the Name gets rendered fine. However, the address seems to appear as [object Object]. I'm sure that i've messed up the way I iterate over the address field. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: Below answer (address.whatever) is correct. Just also note you closed your <template name="task"> with </task> when it should have been closed with </template>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use either the dot notation or the square bracket notation to [access the fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) in an embedded document:

**Dot notation**:

```
<template name="task">
    <li>{{Name}}</li>
    <li>Address
        <ul>
            <li>Building - {{Address.Building}}</li>
            <li>Street - {{Address.Street}}</li>
            <li>Locality - {{Address.Locality}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</template>
```

**Square bracket notation**:

```
<template name="task">
    <li>{{Name}}</li>
    <li>Address
        <ul>
            <li>Building - {{Address["Building"]}}</li>
            <li>Street - {{Address["Street"]}}</li>
            <li>Locality - {{Address["Locality"]}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you Chridam! Looks like I had also dome some errors at while persisting in the DB. I got it working now, after redoing from the beginning.